# Uso do Count() para recorrências de dados

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT
     "metas"."Segmento",
     "metas"."Perfil",
     "metas"."Meta",
     "Negócios"."Nome"
FROM  "metas"
JOIN "Negócios" ON "Negócios"."Perfil"  = "metas"."Perfil"
    AND "Negócios"."Segmento" = "metas"."Segmento"
JOIN "cliente potencial" ON "cliente potencial"."idNegocio" = "Negócios"."Id"  
WHERE "metas"."Mês referência" = 'Novembro 2020'
AND MONTH("cliente potencial"."data") = 11
```

Ela me traz o seguinte retorno:

```
segmento    perfil    meta    nome
seg.a       x         20      joao
seg.a       x         20      pedro
seg.a       x         20      roberto
seg.b       y         30      felipe
seg.b       y         30      marcela
```

Como eu faço um `count` para retornar ao invés do nome a **quantidade de negócios**? O retorno esperado seria assim:

```
segmento    perfil    meta    qtd
seg.a       x         20      3
seg.b       y         30      2
```

Eu tentei fazer um `count` no nome mas só retorna 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar a cláusula GROUP BY com a função de agregação COUNT.

```
SELECT
     "metas"."Segmento",
     "metas"."Perfil",
     "metas"."Meta",
     COUNT(*) AS qtd
FROM  "metas"
JOIN "Negócios" ON "Negócios"."Perfil"  = "metas"."Perfil"
    AND "Negócios"."Segmento" = "metas"."Segmento"
JOIN "cliente potencial" ON "cliente potencial"."idNegocio" = "Negócios"."Id"  
WHERE "metas"."Mês referência" = 'Novembro 2020'
AND MONTH("cliente potencial"."data") = 11
GROUP BY "metas"."Segmento", "metas"."Perfil", "metas"."Meta"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!